# Replace a class within a Dll for unit testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, dll, mocking, googletest

My target is to check DLL using unit testing.
I already have a project that loads the DLL and checks it using Google tests.
Now I want to replace one of the classes within the DLL with a mock and repeat the tests.

Is is possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to test the DLL or an application that uses the DLL? If you are testing the DLL, the tests should be part of the DLL project. You can then statically link to the DLL source code and mock classes in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a little linker trick, which you can use to solve this problem. If the linker finds the class, which you want to replace for testing purposes, in a compilation unit, which belongs to the test project, then it does not search for it in the DLL ;)

So what you need to do is:

1. Add a new source file (.cpp) to the test project (= the one that is linking both the GoogleTest lib and your DLL).
2. In this new .cpp file implement the fake class. Be sure that the fake version of that class has exactly the same signature (i.e. the same class name, namespace, methods).
3. Implement the fake class' methods so they do the fake behaviour.
4. Build the test project. The linker should not complain about missing nor double defined symbols.